# multiple Session requests getting overwritten in nodejs application

Tags: node.js, express-session

I am trying to implement session using nodejs. However i am unable to handle multiple requests in sessions.
**Example:**
If user1 login, data loads.
If user2 login, user 1 data is getting overwritten with user2.
So on refreshing user1 page, again user2 data getting loaded.

```
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
secret: "secterd13",
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: { secure: true }
}));

//Set the session data in login page.
sessionObj = req.session;
sessionObj.Location = "Location1";

//Get in dashboard.

console.log(sessionObj.Location);
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Where you do `sessionObj = req.session` you are creating a global variable and reassigning it on every user. The last user to connect to your server will always overwrite this. If you plan to pass the session data to a template engine, you can use 'res.render('view', { session: req.session })`simply and the session variable will be available in your template. Or you can set the session as global using`res.locals.myVariable = req.session`and`myVariable` will be available in your template.

Comment: Thanks franckstifler. But I still don't understand on how to consume the "myVariable" variable. Can you please give me some sample example of how to implement this ? That will be of great help if you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and I used `req.session` for solving it.

I assigned `unique_id` to each request when it arrives at the server. It worked successfully for me.

Here's my solution:

```
var user_count = 0;

/*********** Authentication request ***********/
var handleAuthRequest = function(req, res) {     
   var unique_id = ++user_count;
   /********* setting unique id to each request session *********/
   req.session.unique_id = unique_id;
   res.redirect("/user/db_op");
}

app.get("/home/get_data", handleAuthRequest);
```